# Significance of Gabriel Engel's name

Tags: analysis, character, antibodies

The antagonist from [*Antibodies (orig.: Antikörper)*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0337573/) carries the name *Gabriel Engel*. Given that "Engel" means "angel", this name is likely not just a coincidence and seems to refer to the *Archangel Gabriel* from Christian mythology. Now this naming could have been done just to contrast *Engel*'s pure evil. But given the many other religious references and motifs of the movie, **I wonder if there is any other meaning to this name in relation to his character or his role in the story** (which would rather be the devil, when seeing his temptation and defiling of *Michael*, apart from his other deeds of course).

Answer (score 1):

In the context of a child murderer, it's quite possible it was also intended to allude to [Josef Mengele](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josef_Mengele) nicknamed *Todesengel* (Angel of Death) which is usually a common theme among characters based on him, such as Dr. Christian Szell in Marathon Man (Der Weisse Engel - The White Angel).

The synopsis mentions he paints beautiful pictures with the children's blood which would be a fitting metaphor for some of his experiments with attempting to correct eye colours to match the Aryan aesthetic (death in the pursuit of beauty, et cetera).

Comment: The rest of the movie doesn't really hint at such an angle, I think. But nevertheless interesting approach.